# Is ist possible to convert a bios setup in Uefi?

Tags: debian, uefi

I had to buy another Notebook. The most newer Computers have uefi. Mine has Bios, so my Installation is in Biosmode.

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf2b569c1

Device     Boot    Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048   62916607   62914560    30G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       62916608   75499519   12582912     6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       75499520 1953525167 1878025648 895,5G 83 Linux
```

Any way to convert my Installation? I know I need a Bootpartition with vfat. Do I really need GPT for Uefi with Linux? No dualboot with Windows. I had a Live-system mit Uefi. So a chroot ist available.

Or should I try  CSM option first?

Distro debian jessie.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, the partition type is just a detail. Getting that detail wrong can make your system unbootable, but it doesn't have any impact once the system is up and running. So the safest option is to let the bootloader have what it wants. Your UEFI BIOS wants GPT, let it have GPT (and you need GPT on large disks anyway).

Just create GPT partitions with the same size or larger as each of your existing partitions, with the same partition number. Be careful with sizes, the new partition must be at least as large, don't get mixed up between SI (1000-based) and binary (1024-based) units. Then copy each partition individually:

```
cat /dev/sdo1 >/dev/sdn1
cat /dev/sdo2 >/dev/sdn2
cat /dev/sdo3 >/dev/sdn3
```

(Replace `sdo` and `sdn` by the appropriate names for your old and new drives. Make sure not to swap them! Check with `file -s /dev/sdn1` that the target doesn't contain a filesystem yet.)

Install the Linux bootloader on the new drive, e.g. `grub-install /dev/sdn` (you can boot Linux directly from EFI but I don't recommend it because it's less flexible if you ever want to pass options, to run memtest, etc.). You don't need to change any Linux configuration file if you keep using the same partition numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought I could something do like that. First purge every closed source drivers. Put my HD in the new Notebook. Chroot with a uefi-Livesystem. Purge every grub package und delete Bootcode from the old grub. Then install the necesarry grub-packages over chroot. GPT do I not need. My Harddrive has onl 1TB And by the way I can not cp with cat. No wrong, so can it go. ^^. And make a boot partiton first with fvat